# I want to compare two multidimational array or json String

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have two json string, i have convert that string into array when i am sending request via curl.

now my problem is i want to send another request if my string is updated.

i have used array_diff but it's giving me error "Notice: Array to string conversion" because its multidimensional.

my json strings are:

```
{"toy":["cycle","doll"],"accessory":["tv"]}
```

and second one is

```
{"toy":["cycle","cat","rabit"],"accessory":["tv","spekers"]}
```

how do i differentiate beetween this and get value if its not in another array.

my converted two array is like this

```
Array
```

`(
    ['toy'] => Array
    (
        [0] => cycle,
        [1] => doll
    ),
    ['accessory'] => Array
    (
        [0] => tv
    )`

`);
Array
(
    ['toy'] => Array
    (
        [0] => cycle,
        [1] => cat,
        [2] => rabit
    ),
    [accessory] => Array
    (
        [0] => tv,
        [1] => spekers
    )`

`);`

Comment: You wrote: "i have used array_diff but it's giving me error "Notice: Array to string conversion" because its multidimensional." Sorry, but that sounds very strange. A call to `array_diff()` certainly does _not_ convert an array into a string. Something else must have been wrong there.

Comment: above is my array i have use this `$results = array_diff($chnsHostIpArray,$chnsArray);`

Comment: Comparing the json notation will make it easy to say if the array differ, but very complex to extract the actual difference. For that `array_diff()` certainly is the better alternative, however you have to create a wrapper around that which is able to work in a recursive manner. So inside the wrapper function you need to call the function itself for each element you find that is an array again. That way you can extract all differences recursively and combine them to a final summed difference.

Comment: Did you read through the documentation of `array_diff()`? In the examples below the description such a recursive function is shown... http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

here is solution i have found

```
public function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) {
    $aReturn = array();

    foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
        if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
            if (is_array($mValue)) {
                $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
                if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; }
            } else {
                if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
    }

    return $aReturn;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-diff.php